# Can I use C++ Dynamyc Link Library ARM build dll in Windows ARM OS in .NET x32/x64 application application?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, arm

The article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/overview states that running x86 and x64 apps in ARM based Windows OS versions is possible. But it is unclear how to use C++ native dll (Dynamic Link Library). What version should I use in this case? Probably ARM, right?

I have tried to run .NET 7 application with code:

```cs
public static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("libraryARM.dll", EntryPoint = "SomeService", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool Run([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string configFile);
}
```

and I've gotten an error message:

```
2023-12-01 09:46:55.2279|FATAL|a|System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)
   at ...NativeMethods.Run(String configFile)
   at a.Main(String[] a)|System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)
   at ...NativeMethods.Run(String configFile)
   at a.Main(String[] a)
```

I'm wondering can I use an ARM pre-build dll file from x86 application in WIndows ARM OS 10/11?

Comment: DLL architecture must match architecture of the process it's loaded into.  If the process is "x86 under emulation" then it must use x86 DLLs.

Comment: The exception would be "ARM64EC", see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/arm64ec   But that's between ARM64 and x64, not x86.